# 2023 Q5 removed aux audio inputs, what options do I have?

Tags: bluetooth, mmi

The center console only has a usbc input. The mmi won’t recognize either a usb Bluetooth receiver or a usb to 3.5 adapter, it tells me the name of the device but says it’s not supported. I tried using a Bluetooth transmitter but the mmi keeps asking for a randomly generated PIN code, and the transmitter dongle doesn’t support that. Other than using a FM transmitter, do I have any other option? Is there like a standalone Bluetooth transmitter that’ll connect to the mmi, like one I can input a pin code into? Or some kind of other adapted I can try for 3.5 to usbc that the mmi will accept?

Comment: You haven’t said which device you are trying to connect to the sound system.

Comment: 3.5” audio cable

Comment: I guess you mean 3.5mm not 3.5 inches

Comment: Presumably you can’t just transfer your audio files to a usb memory stick and play them from that?

Comment: You also haven't told us exactly what you are expecting it the system to do for you? If you're trying to get Apple/Android Car Play to work, it's not going to do it through an 3.5mm jack, nor through the BlueTooth transmitter. I don't think It might do you well to upgrade your phone so you can connect it through the USB-c connector which if available in your vehicle.